# Salvar múltiplas instâncias de uma classe em um List no Java

Tags: java, lista

Estou com um trabalho de faculdade que preciso criar diversas instâncias de um objeto `Pessoa` e salvar essas instâncias em uma listagem para mostrar ao usuário quando necessário (isso vai funcionar como um banco de dados). Como não vimos banco de dados ainda não posso inserir isso nele então estou procurando outra opção. Pesquisando eu vi que isso parece ser possível de se fazer usando Interfaces.

Aqui está minha classe `Pessoa`:

```
public class Pessoa {

    private int id;
    private String nome;
    private char sexo;
    private String telefone;

    Pessoa(int id, String, nome, char sexo, String telefone){
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.sexo = sexo;
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    public int getId(){ return this.id; }
    public void setId(int id){ this.id = id; }

    public String getNome(){ return this.nome; }
    public void setNome(String nome){ this.nome = nome; }

    public char getSexo(){ return this.sexo; }
    public void setSexo(char sexo){ this.sexo = sexo; }

    public char getTelefone(){ return this.telefone; }
    public void setTelefone(String telefone){ this.telefone = telefone;}

}
```

Preciso que na minha aplicação toda vez que eu chamar uma `new Pessoa()` eu tenha como salvar essa objeto em algum lugar do código sem usar arquivos TXT, bases de dados ou semelhantes. Há algum método de fazer isso em Java, algo como um cache?

Comment: ArrayList não resolve?

Comment: Pesquisa sobre EJB e JNDI

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basicamente é isto:

```
ArrayList<Pessoa> pessoas = new ArrayList<>();
pessoas.add(new Pessoa(1, "joão", 'M', "9999-9999"));
pessoas.add(new Pessoa(2, "maria", 'F', "9999-9991"));
for (Pessoa pessoa : pessoas) System.out.println(pessoa.getNome());
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/2Nmmfj). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pgahcszx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/AddToList.java).

Nesse caso a variável `pessoas` é sua tabela, e portanto o "banco de dados". Obviamente não é possível persistir esses dados, mas essa é a base do que deve ser feito.

Comment: sim era isso que eu estava procurando entender... também sei que não é possível persistir mas se manter os dados enquanto a aplicação estiver rodando já vai me servidor para o exercício. Obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Usando uma estrutura básica como um ArrayList, você pode adicionar armazenar cada instância para uma referência futura.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        ArrayList<Pessoa> pessoas = new ArrayList<>();

        pessoas.add(new Pessoa (1, "Pessoa 1", 'M', "9 9999 9999"));
        pessoas.add(new Pessoa (2, "Pessoa 2", 'F', "9 9999 9999"));
        pessoas.add(new Pessoa (3, "Pessoa 3", 'M', "9 9999 9999"));
        pessoas.add(new Pessoa (4, "Pessoa 4", 'F', "9 9999 9999"));
        pessoas.add(new Pessoa (5, "Pessoa 5", 'M', "9 9999 9999"));

        for (Pessoa pessoa : pessoas) {
            System.out.println(pessoa.toString());
        }

    }

}
```

Adicionei o for para exibir como as instâncias estão salvas no ArrayList. Tomei a liberdade de implementar o método toString para facilitar.

O Output é:

```
Id: 1 - Nome: Pessoa 1 - Sexo: M - Telefone: 9 9999 9999
Id: 2 - Nome: Pessoa 2 - Sexo: F - Telefone: 9 9999 9999
Id: 3 - Nome: Pessoa 3 - Sexo: M - Telefone: 9 9999 9999
Id: 4 - Nome: Pessoa 4 - Sexo: F - Telefone: 9 9999 9999
Id: 5 - Nome: Pessoa 5 - Sexo: M - Telefone: 9 9999 9999
```

Caso tenha curiosidade, o método toString implementado é simples:

```
public String toString () {
    return ("Id: " + this.id + 
            " - Nome: " + this.nome + 
            " - Sexo: " + this.sexo +
            " - Telefone: " + this.telefone);
}
```